# Exiting fom actionlistener

Tags: java, multithreading, actionlistener

How do I exit my program from an actionlistener. I have two threads, thread1 and thread2. One thread is in actionlistener. but i want the other thread to exit this actionlistener and manage rest of the code.. How can I do it?

```
sendtkttgt.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        Thread thread1= new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                SendingLogictoTGT obj=new SendingLogictoTGT();
                try {
                    try {
                        obj.main(null);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    }
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                   //  System.exit(1);
                }

            }
        };

      /*Thread thread2= new Thread(){
            public void run(){              
           //I want to exit from this actionlistener 

            }
        };
      */

        thread1.start();

    }
});
```

Comment: Please use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.

Comment: It will exit it, once `start()` is called...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

interrupt() would be your best choice.